# In the evaluation of a call to a function that has an if expression in its body, why is 1 step simplified out of priority?

Tags: if-statement, scheme, racket

In the evaluated BSL expression below, why is the expression "(if true (string-append "fung" "ible") "fung")" done out of order? I know it seems odd to simply it to "(if true "fungible" "fung")", but everything in the most inner parenthesis is supposed to be simplified first correct?

```
(define (bobble s)
  (if (<= (string-length s) 6)
      (string-append s "ible")
      s))
(bobble (substring "fungus" 0 4))

(bobble "fung")

(if (<= (string-length "fung") 6)
    (string-append "fung" "ible")
    "fung")

(if (<= 4 6)
    (string-append "fung" "ible")
    "fung")

(if true
    (string-append "fung" "ible")
    "fung")

(string-append "fung" "ible")

"fungible"
```

Thanks for the help! Just trying to understand what I'm assuming to be "syntax"?

Comment: Not quite. Racket's `if` is *lazy*, so it won't evaluate an expression until absolutely necessary.

Comment: `if` is not "lazy", it just has different evaluation rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scheme `if` is a special form, meaning that its evaluation rules are different from those of, say, procedures. In other words, in an expression such as this:

```
(if (> 4 6)
    (string-append "fung" "ible")
    "fung")
```

The expression `(string-append "fung" "ible")` will never get executed, because the condition `(> 4 6)` is false; only the `"fung"` expression will be evaluated. It's very different from the evaluation rules of a procedure, where all the arguments get evaluated *before* actually invoking the procedure.